# Why does Angular need wrappers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

One thing I still don't understand about Angular is...
Why use $window when i could just use the window global object and get the same result? Why use $timeout when I could use setTimeout, etc.

I use this native javascript code sometimes and it works just fine, so why did AngularJS created these wrappers in the first place?

Comment: "A reference to the browser's window object. While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is a global variable. In angular we always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing.", [say the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is integrated into the digest cycle (will trigger the HTML compiler and the DOM refreshes). Also makes the code easier to test because you can mock the $timeout object and test that it was called.

For example with $timeout, you can call $timeout.flush() in your unit tests and it will act as if the timeout waited the appropriate amount of time and trigger the callback. This makes your tests run much faster which is also good for TDD.

Here is a simple async example - assume that asyncThing.method() uses $timeout and $log to output a message

```
    describe('Async test', function () {
        var asyncThing, $timeout, $log;
        beforeEach(module('async'));
        beforeEach(inject(function (_asyncThing_, _$timeout_, _$log_) {
            asyncThing = _asyncThing_;
            $timeout = _$timeout_;
            $log = _$log_;
       }));
       it('should do some async stuff', function () {
           asyncThing.method(some_arguments);
           $timeout.flush();
           expect($log.info.logs).toContain(['Some output']);
       });
   });
```